# Does display=hidden free browser load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

I have a main page and a canvas element under it (like in agar.io) and I hide my interface and show the canvas when the game begins:

```
const mainpage = document.getElementById('mainpageID');
const mainpage_elems = mainpage.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (let i = 0; i < mainpage_elems.length; i++) {
    const element = mainpage_elems[i];
    element.style.display = "none";
}
```

Will this also help optimize my website so that browser will be running my game faster? Because it knows that all of my other elements are hidden so it can focus on painting canvas. Is that true?

Comment: Well it won't render the element in a redraw although the browser still has a reference to the element so it will still take up space in memory

Comment: Thanks! If it won't render the element it should mean that at least CPU/GPU will have more "time" to draw my canvas.

Comment: Yes, less draw time but unless there are a ton of elements you really won't notice the difference.